# How to create a file instance from a path in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know if there is a way to create a instance of a `file` like the one that is created when a user send an `input file` knowing the path in the project.

I have a folder for `backups` then the user can select the files that he want to recover and i wish to move them from the backup folder to the folder of the model the user is recovering

i have tried this

```
$path = public_path('images/news/');
    foreach($news as $new) {
        foreach($new->images as $image) {
            $imagepath = public_path('images/backup/news/'.$image->image);
            if(file_exists($imagepath)) {

                $this->fileCtrl->copy($imagepath, $path.$new->id);
            }
        }
    }
```

`$this->fileCtrl` is an instance of use `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem as File;`

this try to move the files, but instead of creating a folder with the id and the file inside, it create a file with the id and without extention.

so how can i make the instance of the file, or in other case, how can i prevent it from creating the file and make it create the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously need to create the directory

```
if (!file_exists($imagepath)) {
    //if path doesn't exist create the path and copy
    mkdir($imagepath, 0777, true);
    $this->fileCtrl->copy($imagepath, $path.$new->id);
}else{
    //just copy file to path
    $this->fileCtrl->copy($imagepath, $path.$new->id);
}
```

Comment: you can consider giving an upvote if this helped you ;)